# ng-bind isn't working in label with a custom directive

Tags: angularjs, html, angularjs-directive

I created a directive to add a hint-icon with a description for label, as the following:

```
     propertyWindowModule.directive('hintIcon', {
        restrict: 'A',
        controller: HintIconController,
        controllerAs: 'vm'
     });

     class HintIconController {
       static $inject = ['$element', '$timeout'];
       constructor(private $element:ng.IRootElementService,
                   private $timeout: ng.ITimeoutService) {
           if(!_.isEmpty(this.$element.attr('hint-icon'))) {
               this.$element.attr('title', this.$element.attr('hint-icon'));
               this.$element.append($('<i class="tooltip-icon glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign">').attr('title', this.$element.attr('hint-icon')));
           }
       }
    }
```

And in some views I used it in the label:

```
    <label ng-bind="vm.label" hint-icon="test icon"></label>
```

The the `ng-bind` isn't working, but the `hint-icon` working well - I see the icon of the description with the tooltip, but with no label.

Answer (score 0):

Actually when you define two directive in an element it will throw an exception : "Multiple directives for one scopes!". So you need to define your own ng-bind in hint-icon directive.

```
<label hint-icon="test icon" hint-icon-bind="vm.label"></label>

propertyWindowModule.directive('hintIcon', {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
        hintIconBind: '='
    }, 
    controller: HintIconController,
    controllerAs: 'vm'
})
```

And you use it in your controller like:

```
scope.vm.hintIconBind
```